# virtual pages using PHP only?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a project that I need to let users to create pages on my server. however, I do not want to let users clutter my mysql database by storing the stuff in there so I cannot use mysql database for creating the pages.

I did research this topic and there seem to be a some sort of a plugin for WP that will allow virtual page creation.

is this possible using pure php WITHOUT the use of any database ?

Comment: Where will you store your pages ? Why would it be better than in mysql ?

Comment: @dystroy, they will be stored on my server ofcourse. less connection with mysql database in this project is better for me.

Comment: @user3592614 As a file? such as `.xml`? Which the read/write operations would actually be quicker via MySQL.. I could understand why having fewer dependencies is a good reason, but for having 'fewer' connections, isn't one. If you're using WP as your 'framework' it would be even more *meaningful* to use MySQL.

Comment: @MackieeE, as a html file would be best. but I really do not want to use mysql database. No, I am not using WP. I am developing the site from scratch using php/mysql.

Comment: @user3592614 You've got to store the information, *somewhere*. Otherwise you're just creating many different versions of the same templated page, which certainly isn't virtual ***at all***. There's a reason to why MySQL is the most popular tool for this, because you'll be hard pressed to find faster; more efficient and integrated service. If you want to store variables without a database, it would most certainly would be a file-store system, which would quickly become unmanagable.

Comment: @MackieeE, I APPRECIATE what you are saying mate.. but I need to insist about not using mysql database. that different versions of the same template sounds interesting! any chance of examples?

Comment: I have never heard of "file-store" system! what is that?

Comment: The filestore is nothing magic - it's just the server's filing system. So if your app is stored in `/var/www/project`, you might have a subfolder called `/var/www/project/pages`, in which you store your HTML files.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but wrong.

You can use php to write a html file to your web directory, sure. But that
solution is in no way cleaner or less cluttered than putting stuff in your
database, for a few reasons:

- It's easier to have structured information in the database
- It's a good thing conceptually to separate user data from your program
- It's easier to control access to your database in a safe way, compared 
  to writing user data to the file system

"I really do not want to use mysql database" is not a good reason to give this
up. You might have a good reason, but it's not easy to guess what that is, which
makes suggesting alternatives very difficult.

Comment: reason behind this is because I dedicate a subdomain to each user on my server. so they can create different pages in their own dedicated subdomain and it won't affect my main site at all. that's why I do not have problems with letting them creating pages.

Comment: If you think that what you want is conceptually different from your main site there is nothing wrong with creating a new one, with a different entry point and a different database. The sole purpose of that new site can be to administer the "virtual" sites, so you gain all the advantages without having to worry about clutter.

Comment: not entirely sure if you are agreeing with the concept or disagreeing with it but Thanks for chipping in.